# HTML div mapping

Tags: php, jquery, html

If I defined some div in a code like this:

```
if(...)
{
// code
// code again
       if(...)
        {
          // code
          <div> first div </div>
          //code code
        }
}
         <div> second div </div>
```

So "first div" always appears before the "second div", how can I switch the order of div's displaying? Thanks.

Comment: Umm. Move the second one before the if statement seems obvious enough. What's the problem with that?

Comment: @Quentin lol was thinking exactly the same

Comment: @Quentin :DDD Haha! Damn! So stupid. Can u place ur comment as answer please)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about this (you need div id's)

```
$('#secondDiv').insertBefore('#firstDiv').remove();
```

Change your code to:

```
if(...)
{
// code
// code again
       if(...)
        {
          // code
          <div id='firstDiv'> first div </div>
          //code code
        }
}
<div id='secondDiv'> second div </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can show the second `<div>` in a predetermined place by appending it to another div.  For example:

HTML:

```
<div id="fake-second"></div>
<div id="first"> first div </div>
<div id="second"> second div </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#fake-second").append($("#second").html());
$("#second").hide();
```

**[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dboehf22/)**